# High Load on server due to websocket and Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, server-load

We have 2 servers (Ubuntu 14.04 - 4vCPUs and 12 GB RAM), running a codeigniter application with Apache 2.4.7. These servers are load balanced as well. We have an average of 300 users accessing the site at a time and also the website has refresh functionality in many areas. So we introduced websockets to reduce the load. But even after introducing that, we are facing high load. Node is running on one of these server. After enabling mod_status I can see new connections are not getting opened for apache.

Vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain-ssl/a.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain-ssl/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain-ssl/gd_bundle.crt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/node/socket.io [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
   RewriteRule "^/node/socket.io"  "ws://IPADDRESS:8080/socket.io/" [P,L]
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests off
</VirtualHost>
<Location /node/>
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
       ProxyPass http://IPADDRESS:8080/ connectiontimeout=3 timeout=3 retry=0
       ProxyPassReverse http://IPADDRESS:8080/
</Location>
```

Please let me know the details you need to investigate on this. Thanks

Comment: in your text you are describing 2 problems. a) High load b) "new connections are not getting opened for apache" High load is usually a programming like thing and depends on your application. The other problem could be a limit of concurrent connections (apache and unix have that limit, unix at about 128 connections by default)

Comment: As there arent new slots there could be many pending connections in queue which can lead to high load right ? We tried increasing these values

/etc/sysctl.conf

 fs.file-max = 1000000
 fs.nr_open = 1000000       
 net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
 net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576

Comment: Its actually the other way round. A bad application that doesnt handle the requests fast enough will at some point run out of open connection slots. If the connection amount exceeds the unix limit, then its dropped immidiatly, even before it reaches the apache webserver and shouldnt cause any load, therfore you will not see them in any apache log too. If you run "top", what do you see at the top? Node i guess? So your node application has a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a seperate server for node and redis which has reduced the load.